# Java: Iterate through Nested Classes

Tags: java

Currently, I have a number of nested classes inside an outer class. Each nested class has an overriden `toString` method. My goal is to iterate through these nested classes to access the value returned by the overriden `toString` without initializing every single nested class. I've tried iterating through the array returned by `Class#getDeclaredClasses`

The simplified outer class:

```
class MyClass {
    static class NestedClassOne {
        @Override
        public String toString() {return "One";}
    }
    static class NestedClassTwo {
        @Override
        public String toString() {return "Two";}
    }
}
```

The method I've tried, using the `Class#getDeclaredClasses` array:

```
        for (Class<?> NestedClass : MyClass.class.getDeclaredClasses()) {
            System.out.println(NestedClass.toString());
        }
```

This method, to my dismay, only prints the following:

```
class ... MyClass$NestedClassTwo
class ... MyClass$NestedClassOne
```

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea.  You really shouldn't be using reflection like this.  An `enum` or something similar would likely be a better fit.

Comment: Isn't this because you are calling toString on the class itself and not an instance of it?

Comment: @markspace I'll try using an `enum`, but may I ask why using reflection is a bad idea for this sort of thing?

Comment: "... without initializing every single nested class": hold the phone. You can't call `toString()` *unless* you create an instance of the class. This sounds completely wrongheaded to me. You surely want to iterate over instances, not classes? What is the outer problem here? I agree with @markspace that you seem to be looking for `enum` here.

Comment: It's just kind of obviously super brittle.  It throws numerous exceptions, which enums won't.  If the code structure changes at all (adding different constructor for example) it breaks.  If the method name changes, the compiler can't detect it.  Etc.  I wouldn't want to maintain code that works the way you are asking for.

Comment: What output are you hoping to get?  What do you mean by "initializing" classes?  Do you mean *instantiating*?  Because you can't do much of anything with a class without it being initialized, and class initialization is not directly under your control anyway.

Comment: You could also change your print line to `System.out.println(NestedClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance().toString());`. Still, avoid reflection if you can.

Comment: @PaulRooney But what would be the point? Creating an instance just to print it? What useful information could it possibly contain?

Comment: Agreed useless but possible.

Comment: You _could_ give each nested class a static method, called something _other than_ `toString` and call that instead.  But it still seems like a horrible thing to be doing.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Your `toString()` is invoked directly on the class object.  I.e., it calls `Class<T>.toString()` not `NestedClassOne.toString()`.  For that you need to use reflection:

```
  Class<NestedClassOne> clazz = NestedClassOne.class;
  Method method = clazz.getMethod( "toString" );
  NestedClassOne obj = clazz.newInstance();

  Object result = method.invoke( obj );
  System.out.println( result );
```

I'll repeat my comments however:

This sounds like a bad idea. You really shouldn't be using reflection like this. An `enum` or something similar would likely be a better fit.

It's just kind of obviously super brittle. It throws numerous exceptions, which enums won't. If the code structure changes at all (changing to a different constructor for example) it breaks. If the method name changes, the compiler can't detect it. Etc. I wouldn't want to maintain code that works the way you are asking for.

Answer (score 3):

> My goal is to 1) iterate through these nested classes to 2) access the value returned by the overridden `toString` **without initializing every single nested class**.

The first part you are doing.  The second part is not possible.

The `toString()` methods you are trying to call are instance methods.

- You can't call an instance method until you have created an instance.
- You can't create an instance of a class without triggering<sup>1</sup> the static initialization of the class.

What your attempted code is actually doing is calling the `toString()` method on the `Class` objects.  That gives you the *names* of the classes.

@markspace's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73299318/139985) shows how to create an instance and call the  `toString()` method via reflection.  The caveats are that it assumes that each class has a no-args constructor, and that creating the instances doesn't have undesirable side-effects.

---

<sup>1 - There are scenarios involving classes with cyclic dependencies where an instance of a class may be created before its static initialization has completed.</sup>

---

I agree with @markspace's comments.  I'm not sure what the real purpose of this is, but there is likely to be a better (more robust) way than calling `toString()` methods.   (For example ... using a custom annotation with runtime retention.)

Even if there isn't, the constraint of not initializing the classes seems artificial to me: is this a premature optimization?